# Is there any alternative to setAttribute() other than adding 'unsafe-inline' in CSP policy for adding inline style attr?

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy, inline-styles

I am trying to add inline style attribute on the fly to the DOM. But I can't use unsafe-inline in CSP policy.

CSP does not allow adding inline style attributes unless 'unsafe-inline' is added to the policy.

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div'), body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
div1.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:0;");
body[0].appendChild(div2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative to setAttribute()?

Sure, there's no reason to set inline styles as an attribute. Just use [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style)!

```
var div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.top = 0;
div.style.left = 0;
div.style.margin = 0;
```